# What does importlib.reload change for object (Enum) comparisons?

Tags: python, enums, python-importlib

I have stumbled across a weird problem when reloading modules for which I have found a solution on the internet. However, I am missing an explanation of why this problem occurs (especially regarding Enum comparisons). If anyone is wondering why I would use reload(): When I make changes in the modules, they usually seem to require a kernel restart which I want to prevent.

Take the following fruits.py file with the content:

```py
from enum import Enum


class Fruit(Enum):
    Apple = 1
    Banana = 2
    Pear = 3
```

and try comparing a variable of type Fruit with Fruit.Apple:

(fruits_test.py)

```py
import fruits
from fruits import Fruit
from importlib import reload
reload(fruits)


def check_equality(fruit: Fruit):
    return fruit == Fruit.Apple
```

If I now try to call fruits_test.check_equality in my Jupyter notebook with the following parameters, it will return False:

```py
import fruits_test
from fruits import Fruit

fruits_test.check_equality(Fruit.Apple)
```

However, it will work if reload(fruits) is removed. My question is why this is the case.

Comment: this is documented: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#comparisons

Comment: When you reload, the class is recreated. Instances of the old class are not equal to instances of the new class, even though the numeric values are the same.

Comment: Is there a way to "reload" enum values as well?